# pip loop's through previous versions and download them all

Tags: python, pip

Recently whatever i try to install using pip, i use the command `pip install module`, but for every module that i want to install i get an output like this:

---

at start:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting scikit-learn
Downloading scikit-learn-1.1.1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 6.9 MB 1.0 MB/s
```

and then followed by downloading previous versions all the way down.

```
    Downloading scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 6.9 MB 871 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/40/8bc77d8f536be0a892b37fff19fd81f15935e24724303480f85238ec7f22/scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1.tar.gz#sha256=57538d138ba54407d21e27c306735cbd42a6aae0df6a5a30c7a6edde46b0017d (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/40/8bc77d8f536be0a892b37fff19fd81f15935e24724303480f85238ec7f22/scikit-learn-0.22.2.post1.tar.gz#sha256=57538d138ba54407d21e27c306735cbd42a6aae0df6a5a30c7a6edde46b0017d has inconsistent version: filename has '0.22.2.post1', but metadata has '0.22.2.post1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.22.1.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 6.9 MB 1.0 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/28/5a48b00599b476875415b97bdfdb3849bafb31183c1d785501dbc8a77aa2/scikit-learn-0.22.1.tar.gz#sha256=51ee25330fc244107588545c70e2f3570cfc4017cff09eed69d6e1d82a212b7d (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/18/28/5a48b00599b476875415b97bdfdb3849bafb31183c1d785501dbc8a77aa2/scikit-learn-0.22.1.tar.gz#sha256=51ee25330fc244107588545c70e2f3570cfc4017cff09eed69d6e1d82a212b7d has inconsistent version: filename has '0.22.1', but metadata has '0.22.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.22.tar.gz (6.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 6.9 MB 1.4 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/2c/04e10167991ed6209fb251a212ca7c3148006f335f4aadf1808db2cbeda8/scikit-learn-0.22.tar.gz#sha256=314abf60c073c48a1e95feaae9f3ca47a2139bd77cebb5b877c23a45c9e03012 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/2c/04e10167991ed6209fb251a212ca7c3148006f335f4aadf1808db2cbeda8/scikit-learn-0.22.tar.gz#sha256=314abf60c073c48a1e95feaae9f3ca47a2139bd77cebb5b877c23a45c9e03012 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.22', but metadata has '0.22'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz (12.2 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 12.2 MB 1.0 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ce/9d8c88e68af0a5b5c5d78d8d2b7bcadfd45e1d6afc863ccb9aee30765b06/scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz#sha256=eb9b8ebf59eddd8b96366428238ab27d05a19e89c5516ce294abc35cea75d003 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ce/9d8c88e68af0a5b5c5d78d8d2b7bcadfd45e1d6afc863ccb9aee30765b06/scikit-learn-0.21.3.tar.gz#sha256=eb9b8ebf59eddd8b96366428238ab27d05a19e89c5516ce294abc35cea75d003 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.21.3', but metadata has '0.21.3'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.21.2.tar.gz (12.2 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 12.2 MB 1.0 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/5c/133b464c8d0be7ac8c9414b6ff2ae848808a35ce03b146fc2c43777e51f9/scikit-learn-0.21.2.tar.gz#sha256=0aafc312a55ebf58073151b9308761a5fcfa45b7f7730cea4b1f066f824c72db (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/57/5c/133b464c8d0be7ac8c9414b6ff2ae848808a35ce03b146fc2c43777e51f9/scikit-learn-0.21.2.tar.gz#sha256=0aafc312a55ebf58073151b9308761a5fcfa45b7f7730cea4b1f066f824c72db has inconsistent version: filename has '0.21.2', but metadata has '0.21.2'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.21.1.tar.gz (12.2 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 12.2 MB 913 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/f1/1675d529d6abe989f12a5cb04ecbcbad764eb209ca79a8d030488d0f2b3c/scikit-learn-0.21.1.tar.gz#sha256=228d0611e69e5250946f8cd7bbefec75347950f0ca426d0c518db8f06583f660 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/f1/1675d529d6abe989f12a5cb04ecbcbad764eb209ca79a8d030488d0f2b3c/scikit-learn-0.21.1.tar.gz#sha256=228d0611e69e5250946f8cd7bbefec75347950f0ca426d0c518db8f06583f660 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.21.1', but metadata has '0.21.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.20.4.tar.gz (11.7 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 11.7 MB 222 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/a0/5ec20d7e460d8ebde9ec5e40cda4339c5f546871c3a5bf9228f615b25618/scikit-learn-0.20.4.tar.gz#sha256=dfa8a3f33907614030cdfbc8b6f553dacbecaf09f922244f128af3060a137cfc (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/a0/5ec20d7e460d8ebde9ec5e40cda4339c5f546871c3a5bf9228f615b25618/scikit-learn-0.20.4.tar.gz#sha256=dfa8a3f33907614030cdfbc8b6f553dacbecaf09f922244f128af3060a137cfc has inconsistent version: filename has '0.20.4', but metadata has '0.20.4'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.20.3.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 11.8 MB 876 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cb/3297656b9a3cce0cb60c691d568225fc025d47d3eb668b3c480211801a52/scikit-learn-0.20.3.tar.gz#sha256=c503802a81de18b8b4d40d069f5e363795ee44b1605f38bc104160ca3bfe2c41 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/cb/3297656b9a3cce0cb60c691d568225fc025d47d3eb668b3c480211801a52/scikit-learn-0.20.3.tar.gz#sha256=c503802a81de18b8b4d40d069f5e363795ee44b1605f38bc104160ca3bfe2c41 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.20.3', but metadata has '0.20.3'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.20.2.tar.gz (10.3 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 10.3 MB 1.0 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/0e/8312ac2d7f38537361b943c8cde4b16dadcc9389760bb855323b67bac091/scikit-learn-0.20.2.tar.gz#sha256=bc5bc7c7ee2572a1edcb51698a6caf11fae554194aaab9a38105d9ec419f29e6 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/0e/8312ac2d7f38537361b943c8cde4b16dadcc9389760bb855323b67bac091/scikit-learn-0.20.2.tar.gz#sha256=bc5bc7c7ee2572a1edcb51698a6caf11fae554194aaab9a38105d9ec419f29e6 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.20.2', but metadata has '0.20.2'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.20.1.tar.gz (9.7 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 9.7 MB 886 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/7c/da34889e0a58e801675af88bc6e0dd1fcb4b01d26d1b437eb15df85b50a6/scikit-learn-0.20.1.tar.gz#sha256=fa1869c18fef812e321b9ed875519daefb3a7ea016ba1392526d231a7994e81c (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1a/7c/da34889e0a58e801675af88bc6e0dd1fcb4b01d26d1b437eb15df85b50a6/scikit-learn-0.20.1.tar.gz#sha256=fa1869c18fef812e321b9ed875519daefb3a7ea016ba1392526d231a7994e81c has inconsistent version: filename has '0.20.1', but metadata has '0.20.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.20.0.tar.gz (28.1 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 28.1 MB 1.0 MB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/d7/136a447295adade38e7184618816e94190ded028318062a092daeb972073/scikit-learn-0.20.0.tar.gz#sha256=97d1d971f8ec257011e64b7d655df68081dd3097322690afa1a71a1d755f8c18 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/d7/136a447295adade38e7184618816e94190ded028318062a092daeb972073/scikit-learn-0.20.0.tar.gz#sha256=97d1d971f8ec257011e64b7d655df68081dd3097322690afa1a71a1d755f8c18 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.20.0', but metadata has '0.20.0'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz (9.7 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 9.7 MB 803 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/b6/454cf208be93efa3db50ce06b732328c57ede005d1dcfa71d9a1548530b0/scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz#sha256=b276739a5f863ccacb61999a3067d0895ee291c95502929b2ae56ea1f882e888 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/b6/454cf208be93efa3db50ce06b732328c57ede005d1dcfa71d9a1548530b0/scikit-learn-0.19.2.tar.gz#sha256=b276739a5f863ccacb61999a3067d0895ee291c95502929b2ae56ea1f882e888 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.19.2', but metadata has '0.19.2'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz (9.5 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 9.5 MB 863 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/2c/5edf2488897cad4fb8c4ace86369833552615bf264460ae4ef6e1f258982/scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz#sha256=5ca0ad32ee04abe0d4ba02c8d89d501b4e5e0304bdf4d45c2e9875a735b323a0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/2c/5edf2488897cad4fb8c4ace86369833552615bf264460ae4ef6e1f258982/scikit-learn-0.19.1.tar.gz#sha256=5ca0ad32ee04abe0d4ba02c8d89d501b4e5e0304bdf4d45c2e9875a735b323a0 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.19.1', but metadata has '0.19.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.19.0.tar.gz (9.3 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 9.3 MB 883 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/38/e3b0333e661ab411545583cb24940223917fe7ffc9c68a77730dce3b10b0/scikit-learn-0.19.0.tar.gz#sha256=24f5cb67559e0df27827b1804b197431c08880d2ec9285724fac90906830021f (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/38/e3b0333e661ab411545583cb24940223917fe7ffc9c68a77730dce3b10b0/scikit-learn-0.19.0.tar.gz#sha256=24f5cb67559e0df27827b1804b197431c08880d2ec9285724fac90906830021f has inconsistent version: filename has '0.19.0', but metadata has '0.19.0'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.18.2.tar.gz (9.2 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 9.2 MB 858 kB/s            
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/c2/21c612f3a1b1ba97b7b4bbd1fcdc59b475a09e25efad13fec4565ab9d563/scikit-learn-0.18.2.tar.gz#sha256=f78c3e11bf38838eaf637cdd9e8d6b575a4a4048d1670a03a72b0d00d3f39ffa (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/26/c2/21c612f3a1b1ba97b7b4bbd1fcdc59b475a09e25efad13fec4565ab9d563/scikit-learn-0.18.2.tar.gz#sha256=f78c3e11bf38838eaf637cdd9e8d6b575a4a4048d1670a03a72b0d00d3f39ffa has inconsistent version: filename has '0.18.2', but metadata has '0.18.2'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.18.1.tar.gz (8.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 8.9 MB 1.0 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/dc/5fb2834511eef6f86e17b6ec41c0c7a60733f79633827e75aaa55029a9fa/scikit-learn-0.18.1.tar.gz#sha256=1eddfc27bb37597a5d514de1299981758e660e0af56981c0bfdf462c9568a60c (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/dc/5fb2834511eef6f86e17b6ec41c0c7a60733f79633827e75aaa55029a9fa/scikit-learn-0.18.1.tar.gz#sha256=1eddfc27bb37597a5d514de1299981758e660e0af56981c0bfdf462c9568a60c has inconsistent version: filename has '0.18.1', but metadata has '0.18.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.18.tar.gz (8.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 8.9 MB 1.0 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/cf/9a1fe9d70e8fefe4f325a439a6380cd7059d1af8baa646519f4b0473b879/scikit-learn-0.18.tar.gz#sha256=240009789d6495240b332e059cbd2499f4d2981c93873983c9e1d5189f90315f (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/cf/9a1fe9d70e8fefe4f325a439a6380cd7059d1af8baa646519f4b0473b879/scikit-learn-0.18.tar.gz#sha256=240009789d6495240b332e059cbd2499f4d2981c93873983c9e1d5189f90315f has inconsistent version: filename has '0.18', but metadata has '0.18'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.17.1.tar.gz (7.9 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 7.9 MB 1.0 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/1d/9c775f9403565f68aa23f9cef76c817a7115abd7ca1e1c5958a68c49fb6f/scikit-learn-0.17.1.tar.gz#sha256=9f4cf58e57d81783289fc503caaed1f210bab49b7a6f680bf3c04b1e0a96e5f0 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0d/1d/9c775f9403565f68aa23f9cef76c817a7115abd7ca1e1c5958a68c49fb6f/scikit-learn-0.17.1.tar.gz#sha256=9f4cf58e57d81783289fc503caaed1f210bab49b7a6f680bf3c04b1e0a96e5f0 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.17.1', but metadata has '0.17.1'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.17.tar.gz (7.8 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 7.8 MB 1.0 MB/s
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/b8/c420dce3f72d95e06f7c1e50a6e705f4e8b6078d7d6db38425ac77ae3fab/scikit-learn-0.17.tar.gz#sha256=23a5b6804524cb2cd54d8310010169511c7633dcf69af7439747eec02677f314 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/). Requested scikit-learn from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/b8/c420dce3f72d95e06f7c1e50a6e705f4e8b6078d7d6db38425ac77ae3fab/scikit-learn-0.17.tar.gz#sha256=23a5b6804524cb2cd54d8310010169511c7633dcf69af7439747eec02677f314 has inconsistent version: filename has '0.17', but metadata has '0.17'
Downloading scikit-learn-0.16.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 7.3 MB 1.0 MB/s
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

it just loop's through all previous versions until either there is none left or you run out of space :(
and even after downloading them all it doesn't install any of them.
i also tried `pip install module==version`

---

pip ver:

```
pip 21.0 from /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
```

Comment: Have you tried `pip install scikit-learn==1.1.1`?

Comment: didn't work. but i may just found another solution. appreciate your help :)

Comment: Whoa, how little space do you have left on your device?

Comment: try upgrade pip, this issue has been there https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9284

Comment: @KellyBundy i have 14GB free. i don't know what predefined behavior of this makes it say so. but it sound's fair after downloading that much of the prev versions.

Comment: @sahasrara62 it worked thank's. i should have tried it before. but in my distro package manager it was already up to date, but anyway it's better i mentioned it, it can prevent people just creating github issues and so on only to found out solution was this easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just doing the operation as root fixed the problem! (using `sudo pip install scikit-learn`)
note: according to comments this solution isn't the perfect/safe one!

the proper solution is to just upgrade the pip using `pip install --upgrade pip` (for now i upgraded to v22.1)

again according to comments and [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9284#issuecomment-800843707) github issue, the source of this was some conflicts. making the pip testing all previous versions to find the one without conflicts(and it never does).

Comment: using sudo is not the solution

Comment: It could be that you have already installed scikit from your distro's package manager. So when python tries to update, there is a rights violation. In this case, you don't want to overwrite the files managed by your distro with pip versions. If you don't need the latest scikit, just stick with what your distro is giving you. Otherwise, uninstall the distro version first, or use a python venv for your install. Maybe nothing will go wrong, but maybe your distro will try its own scikit update sometime, scrambling things.